# Method not found: 'Void LinqKit.Extensions.ForEach

Tags: c#, .net, linq

After LinqKit update that I have just done, my Visual Studio 2015 started to throw an exception at compile time:

Method not found: 'Void LinqKit.Extensions.ForEach(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!!0>, System.Action`1)'.

I have updated my LinqKit from 1.1.4.1 version to 1.1.7.1 version.

I have used many ForEach statements in my code but fortunately the exception that is thrown is not saying the exact line that causes the error. The exception pop-up is only pointing out a method invocation that contains those ForEach statements.

Thanks in advance.

### Edit

I have made ForEach invocations in such way that:

```
someCollection.ForEach(s => {
    // something here
});

dictionaryA.ForEach(d => {
    // something here
});

dictionaryB.Keys.ForEach(d => {
    // something here
})
```

Comment: Why are you not using a `foreach` loop?

Comment: The source doesn't have a ForEach method defined. Soo.. ya. It's not there. https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/commit/96626e863784bac5d324c5cb4b189f5cb902d1ab

Comment: yes, thank you this is the real cause.. Visual Studio 2015 requires updates on all LinqKit dlls for all projects inside solution to display actual line of compilation error before build is started..

Answer (score 2):

This method was not related to LinqKit and was removed.

.NET has .ToList() for `List<T>` by default so just say `someCollection.ToList().ForEach(...)`

The reason that ToList is not implemented for IEnumerable in .NET is that IEnumerable should be thought as immutable collection and ForEach is a mutable method causing some side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

The [link](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit/commit/96626e863784bac5d324c5cb4b189f5cb902d1ab) that `Chee's Burgers` provides shows that when `ForEach` existed, it was just an extension method that applied your "something here" on each element in the collection as follows:

```
/// <summary> Default side-effect style enumeration </summary>
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var element in source)
        action(element);
}
```

So you can either add that extension method yourself, or you should be able to update your code as follows

```
foreach(var s in someCollection)
{
    // something here
}

foreach(var d in dictionaryA)
{
    // something here
}

foreach(var d in dictionaryB.Keys)
{
    // something here
}
```